# How to detect the url opening from web browser(chrome) or webview(mobile app) using jquery/javascript in the website?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, kentico

I can detect android easily from the website(using user agent) easily. But now the problem with detecting url being opened from webview(app) or chrome(browser) in the mobile by using jquery. This is to detect thus can apply deeplink excluding with webview. I don't really wanna do changes in mobile development site.

When the link opening in chrome(mobile), there is no issues.. The link have a deeplink of containing app://article. When the link is opened from the webview in an app, the deeplink causing issues to display :
err_unknown_url_scheme error

Is there any option to detect where the link being opened and not applying deeplink in that part only. Something that can only do from website itself by using jquery only.

Thanks and sorry for the improper explanation just now. Hopefully can help me to resolve with this.

Comment: `native web browser` what is this? I don't think Android has any `native web browser`

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I have edited my question.. please look into it..

Comment: you can detect chrome with user-agent, but detecting WebView is very hard, as it's user-agent can be set to anything.

Comment: Please edit not only question title, but the question body too

Comment: Actually on which side do you want to detect it? In the app opened with deep link?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I solved by differentiating native browser and chrome with "version".

```
var nua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var is_native = ((nua.indexOf('mozilla/5.0') > -1 && nua.indexOf('android ') > -1 && nua.indexOf('applewebkit') > -1) && (nua.indexOf('version') > -1)); //native browser?
```

Thanks anyway.